# How to write an efficient Fibonacci summing algorithm

Tags: java, performance, loops, fibonacci

Project Euler, problem 2: Determine the sum of the even numbers in the Fibonacci sequence up to 4 000 000. First I tried to
use a recursive algorithm for the sequence but I realized I dont have all the time in the world so I now use an iterative. It is still
extremely slow. Can I improve my code?

```
public class Euler2Correct {
    public static int Fibonacci(int j){ 
        /**
         * Metod for returnerning number [I]j[/I] in the sequence.
         * 
         */
        if(j<=1){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(j==2){
            return 2;
        }

        int tmp;
        int a=2;
        int b=1;

        for(int k=3; k<=j; k++){
            tmp=a+b;
            b=a;
            a=tmp;
        }

        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
       int s=0;

        for(int i=2; i<4000000; i=i+3){ //Every three number is even
            s = s + Fibonacci(i);
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }  
}
```

Comment: The complexity of your algorithm is n squared. You can get it down to just n.

Comment: Why the downvote? Because of the nature of the problem? Because I've put an effort

Comment: @EricAm People tend not to like when questions ask for help with homework or internet puzzles. But I'm not one of the downvoters (just explaining why I think you're getting them)

Comment: Ok, I got. Fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are recalculating the Fibonacci number over and over again from scratch. If you keep the running total in the Fibonacci method, you can use the previous results to prevent doing all that extra work.

Here's the modified version of your code, I tried to keep it as similar as possible

```
public class Euler2Correct {
  public static int Fibonacci(int j) {
    int tmp;
    int a = 2;
    int b = 1;
    int total = 0;

    do {
      if(isEven(a)) total +=a;
      tmp = a + b;
      b = a;
      a = tmp;      
    } while (a < j);

    return total;

  }

  private static boolean isEven(int a) {
    return (a & 1) == 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Notice there is no more loop here
    System.out.println(Fibonacci(4_000_000));
  }
}
```